# iPhone and iPad return a blank page in browser test on browserstack

Tags: ipad, browser, browserstack

I'm at the point of testing my website using default browsers on browserstack. All my pages seem okay on all browsers except

- iPhone 6 Plus(portrait)
- iPad 4th(portrait)
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1(portrait)
- iPhone 5S(portrait)

which are showing a blank for all pages.

I have searched the internet and found that sometimes this may be due to the use of Flash. But I haven't used Flash. The only other info I can find is regarding apps. I just have a fairly standard website. I am stuck now and I don't know where I should be looking for errors. Has anyone else encountered this problem please, am I missing soemthing obvious?

Comment: Would recommend dropping an email to support@browserstack.com, as they'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem  with Samsung Galaxy by removing:`<!--if (screen.width >= 800) {window.location = "http://www.website";}//-->`

from head. It was causing to cycle through several urls without loading.

Comment: I will have to put back the script <!--if (screen.width >= 800) {window.location = "http://www.website";}//-->.  Becasue despite having <meta name="Robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /> 
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir"/>
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOARCHIVE"> in the head section, results for mobile pages arre showing up in google which is not going to be a good look on a dektop.